# Project structure to improve the performances in a .NET 8 MAUI app

Tags: c#, performance, maui, .net-8.0

I'm creating my .NET 8 MAUI application for all platforms. I have a single project with everything in it:

- UI
- Models
- ViewModels
- Services
- Extensions
- Behaviours
- Persistence

and so on. The performance of the app on a real device seems quite acceptable but I'm wondering if there are some guidelines, best practices or advice to follow to improve the responsiveness of the application.

For example, can moving outside the main project all the parts (models, services, view models...) improve the performance?

### Update

Just a clarification. When I said, project structure, I meant to move into `dll` part of the main application. For example, the models in a different project and then add it as a project reference to the main project.

As another way to see my question is: in the past with `Xamarin`, I used to divide the project in *Platform* for platform-specific implementation, the *UI* that contains all the views, controls, behaviours etc, and then *Models* that contains data models, dto, viewmodels etc.

[image]

This project structure wasn't for improving the performance but only to give to the developers a nice way to understand where to put what.

Basically, my question is if I split the project in multiple dll, can the performance improve or it is completely irrelevant?

Comment: I don't think project structure has any impact on performance except maybe the first load of each external assembly

Comment: there are thousands of things that impact performance, but project structure is not one of them

Comment: Moving parts out of the main thread might help but not moving out of the main project.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if a class comes from the main assembly or another surrounding assembly has no impact on performance when everything is loaded. There might be a small impact when you first use something from another assembly for the first time. Then a chain of loading dependencies of dependencies might start. But it would be a one-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

So from my experience (Yours may vary), I tried to focus on making as much of the processing(services, extensions) as I can on an ASP.net Core web app that I then connect to from Maui by API calls. I Deployed my ASP.net Core on Azure, it's super easy and nice to work with. It's also not expensive for a small-scale project ~$14 a month including a SQL DB. We have a similar structure at the company I work in. Try Azure services, they work very well in Visual Studio since there natively integrated.

As for UI, I used Syncfusion Libraries which are relatively fast and use a lot less code, which also may increase performance. It's free and you should definitely use it! [enter link description here](https://www.syncfusion.com/maui-controls)

You can also refer to this link from Microsoft which also helps a lot:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/performance?view=net-maui-8.0

Lastly, My thoughts:
I read some comments from other blog posts on how performance shouldn't be looked at until you get there(meaning your app is actually slow and it's worth investing the time to improve performance). Keep in mind smartphones are a lot more powerful now than ever, there slowly reaching laptop performance, Some phones now have 12GB Ram which meaning memory management is less of a problem and etc. I think you shouldn't stress too much on performance.

Comment: How does server side stuff, mobile devices. hosting costs etc. come into play when he simply talking about a MAUI App?

Comment: I tried helping from many points of view. He seems like he's fresh into Maui, I have fair experience from personal and cooperate projects. Thought I could help :)

Comment: Thank you for the help, anyway. It is true, I'm quite new on Maui but long experience with Xamarin.

Comment: You welcome, Yes it seems now I may have been off topic. Sorry about that!